# Let $G$ be a "Normed" Abelian Group, is this a topological equivalent Norm over $G$?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $G$ be an abelian group. We say $\Vert \cdot \Vert : G \rightarrow \Bbb R_{\ge0}$ is a norm if it satisfies

1. $\Vert x \Vert =0 \Leftrightarrow x=0$
2. $\Vert -x \Vert = \Vert x \Vert$
3. $\Vert x+y \Vert \le \Vert x \Vert+\Vert y \Vert$

It's easy to prove $d(x,y)=\Vert x-y \Vert$ is a metric over $G$ and satisfies

- $d(x+z,y+z)=d(x,y)$
- $d(-x,-y)=d(x,y)$

In fact, any metric over $G$ satisfying this properties is induced  by a Norm over $G$. We say two Norms over $G$ are topologically equivalent if they induce the same topology over $G$.

Let $G$ be an abelian group with a Norm, I've manage to prove the following function
$$\Vert x \Vert_*= \frac{\Vert x \Vert}{1+\Vert x \Vert}$$
is a norm over $G$ and is topologically equivalent to the original norm. Also $\Vert x \Vert_*<1$ for all $x \in G$ and if $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is unbounded then $\sup_{x \in G}{\Vert x \Vert}_*=1$.
Now let $G$ be an abelian group with a norm such that $\Vert x \Vert<1 \ \ \forall \ x \in G$ and $\sup_{x \in G}{\Vert x \Vert}=1$, is the following function a norm over $G$?
$$\Vert x \Vert^*= \frac{\Vert x \Vert}{1-\Vert x \Vert}$$
Is it topologically equivalent to the original norm? If this is true then the unbounded norms over an abelian group $G$ are in bijection with the bounded norms with $\Vert x \Vert<1 \ \ \forall \ x \in G$ and $\sup_{x \in G}{\Vert x \Vert}=1$, and the biyection "behaves well" with the topology (meaning it preserves the relation "being topologically equivalent"). This is what I'm trying to prove.